# How to deal with mix of CommonJS and ECMAScript modules in 3rd party packages

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-modules, graphql-yoga

I'm writing a NodeJS backend for an application.  It uses graphql and graphql-yoga.  The application runs fine using tsx, but when I attempt to build the application I get several instances of this error (from different .cts files in that same folder):

> node_modules/@graphql-yoga/subscription/typings/operator/map.d.cts:1:26
>
> - error TS1479: The current file is a CommonJS module whose imports will produce 'require' calls; however, the referenced file is an
>   ECMAScript module and cannot be imported with 'require'. Consider
>   writing a dynamic 'import("@repeaterjs/repeater")' call instead.
>
> 1 import { Repeater } from '@repeaterjs/repeater';

Is there a way to adjust my compiler options or something to fix this?

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "module": "Node16",
    "moduleResolution": "Node16",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports" : true,
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2020",
  },
  "type": "module",
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "paths": {
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./src/**/*.d.ts",
    "./test/**/*.ts",
    "./test/**/*.d.ts",
    "index.ts",
    "./.eslintrc.js",
    "./jest.config.js",
  ]
}
```

Comment: Seems like an issue with how your dependency was published.

Comment: What is odd is that your transitive dependency `@repeaterjs/repeater` has published a CJS build but uses `"private": true`: https://github.com/repeaterjs/repeater/blob/master/packages/repeater/rollup.config.js#L22. Seems both `graphql-yoga/subscription` and `@repeaterjs/repeater` support an ES build correctly, you might want to consider transitioning your project to ES modules.